# Tensorflow reusing of Multi-Layered LSTM Network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, tensorboard

I am trying to use same LSTM architecture for different inputs and hence passing the same cells while unfolding the bidirectional LSTM while unfolding different inputs. I am not sure if it's creating two whole different LSTM Networks. It looks like there are two different nodes in my Graph. My code and graph looks something like this:

```
def get_multirnn_cell(self):
    cells = []
    for _ in range(config.n_layers):
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(config.n_hidden, initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer())
        dropout_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=cell,
                                                     input_keep_prob=config.keep_prob,
                                                     output_keep_prob=config.keep_prob)
        cells.append(dropout_cell)
    return cells

def add_lstm_op(self):

    with tf.variable_scope('lstm'):
        cells_fw = self.get_multirnn_cell()
        cells_bw = self.get_multirnn_cell()
        cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells_fw)
        cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells_bw)
        (_, _), (state_one_fw, state_one_bw) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw,
                                                                               inputs=self.question_one,
                                                                               sequence_length=self.seql_one,
                                                                               dtype=tf.float32)

        self.state_one = tf.concat([state_one_fw[-1].h, state_one_bw[-1].h], name='state_one', axis=-1)

        # self.state_one = tf.concat([state_one_fw, state_one_bw], axis=-1)
        # [batch_size, 2*hidden_size]

        (_, _), (state_two_fw, state_two_bw) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw, cell_bw,
                                                                               inputs=self.question_two,
                                                                               sequence_length=self.seql_two,
                                                                               dtype=tf.float32)
        self.state_two = tf.concat([state_two_fw[-1].h, state_two_bw[-1].h], name='state_two', axis=-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the `multirnn_cell`, you could pass a `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE` for the `variable_scope`.

```
with tf.variable_scope('lstm', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
```

See the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope).

Comment: Hi, I have tried using that too. Does according to the graph two separate networks are created or they are shown separately as they have different in inputs?

Comment: They could be created with two set of variables or sharing variables. We cannot tell from your current graph. You should be able to click into the two "bidirectional_rnn" blocks on tensorboard and see if they really link to the same set of variables.